# How to see Flutter API website for a specific version?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to see the Flutter API site for a specific version?

Ex: Someone added a example in `Hero` class in this [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/74415) 
`Hero` class in version `2.0.3` - [heroes.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2.0.3/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/heroes.dart) 
`Hero` class in version `2.1.0-10.0.pre` - [heroes.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2.1.0-10.0.pre/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/heroes.dart) 
Diff Addition - [diff](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/74415/files#diff-00cb27aabcd395d28ae6613c147dc619e0cfd6b3735afec0371a9fa2ec0b5b39)

At this point in time `2.0.3` is stable so cannot see the example added to the `Hero` class. 
So, is there any way to see the changes in a specific version on https://api.flutter.dev site?

Dart API can be browsed for a specific version. 
Dart API for version 2.12.4 - https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/index.html 
Dart API for version 2.12.0 - https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/index.html

Edit 1 -

Contents in the `master` branch of Flutter API can be viewed at https://master-api.flutter.dev

Comment: Not a specific version but you can check the master branch documentation at https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html.

Answer (score 1):

The `master` branch documentation is always available at https://master-api.flutter.dev.

[Here is the Hero widget page.](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html)

Comment: How's that answering the question asked?